# Is there a way to iterate through a set?

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I have a set $X=\{x_1,x_2,...x_n\}$
and I want to define a function:
$$f(X)=\prod_{j=1}^n{\sum_{i=j}^nx_i \choose x_j}$$

However, in this function I'm treating this set as a sequence, as sets don't have a particular order. The problem is that I can't think of a way of working around this, without having to define the sequence (which I'm also not sure how to do, as these elements don't have any inherit order).
In addition the output of the function is invariant of the order of $x_1,x_2,...x_n$.

Is there a workaround to this situation, allowing me to iterate through the set?

One idea I had is to use the form:
$$f(X)=\prod_{x_i\in{X}}{?? \choose x_i}$$
But I don't know how I would express the top part of the binomial coefficient, as it depends on all of the other elements before.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're saying that the elements don't have any particular order, but your summation is order dependent.

Comment: thats the problem I'm running into

Comment: There isn't anything preventing you from iterating through the set.  The issue you're having is nothing more than an issue with notation.  The sum of finitely many elements of a set of real numbers is well defined, regardless of how they're labelled.  For clarity, it can help to label them.

Comment: @mathematician: That's not the issue here.

Comment: The thing is that the output is invariant of the order of these elements

Comment: How would I go about defining the sequence?

Comment: The point is the order doesn't matter.  Put them in any order you want, you get the same thing.  Define the sequence to be any sequence of the elements of the set.  In place of your question marks you could write in " sum(X) " and it would be clear what you mean.  There is no magic that lets you add things up.

Comment: @mathematician However, a normal set is unordered, so I would have to use it as a sequence, as the summation in the binomial coefficient is order dependent.

Comment: Not all sets have orders some do.  All countable sets can be indexed to be placed in order.  Your set is defined as a sequence with an index and is handed to you on a silver platter in order.  Your concern are completely unnecessary.  However had you set be uncountable, then you would have very real concerns.

Comment: Oh, wow, I did not see the $j$ in there.

Comment: "This treats the set as a sequence". That's because the set **is** a sequence. A sequence is a countable set that has been indexed. This is a finite set that has an index. You have no problem whatsoever.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the help!

Comment: See my amended answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

If the output of the function is indeed independent of the order, just use your first expression and write explicitly that the order does not matter. Note that your formula already implies using an order because the upper argument adds up only the elements comping *after* the one in the lower argument.

If the result does depend on the order, you'll not be able to avoid explicitly specifying the order.

Alternatively, you could define your function recursively:
\begin{aligned}
f(\emptyset) &= 1\\
f(X\cup\{a\}) &= f(X)\times{a+\sum_{x\in X}x \choose a} \text{ where } a\notin X
\end{aligned}
Of course this is only well-defined if your function really does not depend on the order.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me that $f(X)$ is a product of terms where each term individually depends on the order of the sequence, but where the product itself does not.

As such, you will probably need to fix an order $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ in order to express the terms of the product. Having chosen such an order, you might write:

$$f(X) = \prod_{x_i \in X}   {\sum_{i\leq j\leq n} x_j\choose x_i} $$

which is somewhat loose, but conveys the behavior of the function.